# FILE pointer in C, dynamically allocated?

Tags: c, file

(1)WHen I am using a FILE pointer in C and forgot to close it. My computer told me that it was a memory leak in the program. I feel does it mean that we dynamically allocate heap space for the file pointer?

Comment: This is up to the implementation (i.e. the compiler, its libraries, perhaps the OS).   You need to call one `fclose` for each `fopen` which succeeded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I do believe the pointer returned by the fopen function is initialized with malloc, so without properly freeing it (using fclose) there will be a memory leak when the program exits
2. There should be no need to call fclose if you never used fopen. I can't think of a reason you'd need a FILE pointer if you weren't going to use fopen, though.

Comment: What about `stdout`, its a `FILE *`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your program terminated by returning from `main` or by calling `exit()`, all open files are closed automatically (and all out streams are flushed). This is specified in the C standard; see [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section 7.21.3, paragraph 5.

It's good practice to explicitly call `fclose()` on any `FILE*` objects obtained from `fopen()`, but it's not entirely necessary.

As for your second question, if I understand it correctly, if you don't call `fopen()` then you shouldn't call `fclose()`. Passing a `FILE*` to value to `fclose()` if it wasn't obtained by calling `fopen()` or some similar function is an error.

If you have a memory leak in your program (how do you know; did you run valgrind?), then it's probably something else.

Answer (score 0):

`fopen()` might use dynamically allocated memory, if you do not close it, the memory will not be relased and tools such as valgrind reports it as a memory leak.

(As for your 2. question, I do not understand what you're asking)